# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation truncate pdo

Tags: mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, truncate

I keep getting this:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''`TABLE 16`''

But i can't find the error in my code:

```
$show = $conn->query('SHOW TABLES');

$show->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

while($row = $show->fetch()) {

  $tbl = "`".$row[0]."`";  

  $trunc = $conn->prepare('TRUNCATE TABLE :tbl');

  $trunc->bindParam(':tbl', $tbl, PDO::PARAM_STR, 64);// sanitize data

  $trunc->execute();
}
```

If i change it like this,it work:

```
$trunc= $conn->query('TRUNCATE TABLE `TABLE 16`');
```

Comment: This has been asked many times before. You cannot use parameters to bind a table name.

Comment: ... because the whole purpose of prepared statements is code and data separation.

Comment: Your problem is based on the confusion. You have to understand that bindParam doesn't "sanitize" anything, its purpose is different

Comment: @YourCommonSense , as far as i've read it bind the variable to the placeholder and prepare it for query, does it have another purpose? By preparing i mean eliminating some security risks like injection and some others

Comment: Unfortunately, such thing like "some magic that eliminates all injection risks" just doesn't exist. Prepared statements can protect your string and numeric data. That's all.

Comment: I'm not expecting for some magic things to do the work for me.Those last few days i kept reading and asking about best practices in matter of readability and efficiency and all i could find is that i should use prepared statements instead of the old fashioned way when i was validating data with my own function before storing it,with the deprecated mysql.So that's what i've done,but seems like,despite de rumors , those built in things have a lot of problems ...

Comment: Speaking of my case , where the table names consist only of alphanumeric characters , prepared statements should be enough . That's what others also told me...

Comment: Prepared statements can't eliminate injection risk if you let the user choose the table name: your code is designed to allow wiping out arbitrary tables.